# Quickblox Messages Not saved to History

Tags: ios, quickblox

Quickblox messages are not getting saved to history,the messages are delivered to other user but not view able in dialog history or not getting saved

Comment: [Chat History](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/1:1_Chat_history)

Comment: [Chat Guide](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API)